# Rails routing for Redmine Plugin - ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, redmine-plugins

I am new in ruby-on-rails and i am trying to develop plugin for Redmine. I have next configuration:

```
root:/usr/share/redmine# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
root:/usr/share/redmine# rails -v
Rails 3.2.22
```

Then i created Redmine plugin in next way:

```
export RAILS_ENV="production" 

bundle exec ruby script/rails generate redmine_plugin redmine_requirements

bundle exec ruby script/rails generate redmine_plugin_model redmine_requirements AddProject Name:string  

bundle exec ruby script/rails generate redmine_plugin_controller redmine_requirements AddProject SaveProjectInformation

# ... edit routes.rb, so that:

root:/usr/share/redmine# more   plugins/redmine_requirements/config/routes.rb
# Plugin's routes
# See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
match "requirements" => "AddProject#SaveProjectInformation"

# ... then exec

bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate
service apache2 restart
```

---

Finally, when i try to access http://localhost/requirements, i have next error and error in the log file:

#### Page not found
The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.

```
Started GET "/requirements" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2016-04-14 15:45:40 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant AddProjectController):
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
```

---

Could anyone help me to fix it? 
Thank You in advance!

Comment: check your controller. Do you have `AddProjectController` and try to rewrite your route to 

`get 'requirements', to: 'add_project'#save_project_information' `

Comment: my controller is next:
` more ../app/controllers/AddProject_controller.rb
class AddProjectController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  def saveprojectinformation
  end
end`


route rewriting doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to find a similar plugin for what you want to do because Redmine is not really documented and, trust me, im in the same position than you.

Something you can do to check for more detailed errors is changing the environment from production to development (without really changing it) doing this:

(Don't develop the plugin in the production server, always in a local one).

> Navigate to \config\environment , make a copy of production.rb and change the content for the one inside development.rb

After this you will be able to see the development error reports.

Well, now to the problem itself:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant AddProjectController)
```

This line of code is telling you that the AddProjectController doesn't exists. Check the file , inside controllers, called add_project_controller.rb or something like that and confirm that the first line of the controller is called AddProjectController.

It should be like this :

```
class AddProjectController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Hi Ruben! 

Thank You very much for your answer! i already had found the problem: model and controller had the same names. i just renamed controller into new name and now it works fine.